# KnockoutJS Mapping toJS ignore nested keys

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Can I not ignore nested properties when using toJS in KnockoutJS' mapping plugin?

Example:

```
var obj = {
    "akey": {
        "anestedkey": "ignore",
        "anotherkey": "value"
    }
};

console.log(ko.mapping.toJS(obj, {
    "ignore": ["akey.anestedkey"],
}));
```

Expected output is

```
{
    akey: {
        anotherkey: "value"   
    }
}
```

Actual output is

```
{
    akey: {
        anestedkey: "ignore"
        anotherkey: "value"   
    }
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/48KVU/**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you remove the parent (if you know your key is unique in obj or if you want to remove all occurences):

```
var obj = {
    "akey": {
        "anestedkey": "ignore",
        "anotherkey": "value"
    }
};

console.log(ko.mapping.toJS(obj, {
    "ignore": ["anestedkey"], //here
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/48KVU/1/

Comment: Huh, I would never have thought of that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Esben I had the same with the `create` option :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only provide options when mapping; `toJS` and `toJSON` are used for unmapping.

Using nested keys works fine when mapping:

```
var obj = {
    "akey": {
        "anestedkey": "ignore",
        "anotherkey": "value"
    }
};

console.log(ko.mapping.fromJS(obj, {
    "ignore": ["akey.anestedkey"],
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjroesink/Sg5KK/

Comment: I am fairly sure the options are supposed to work in the opposite direction as well. At least ignore, copy etc. works at the top level, i.e. ignore: ["akey"] works when unmapping.